# Why config cache not working on my shared hosting in Laravel 8

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I uploaded my laravel site in shared hosting, my site is working well in localhost, but the CSS is not working on the server. I want to clear cache but not run artisan command in shared hosting. I tried following.

```
// Clear route cache:
Route::get('/route-clear', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:clear');
    return 'Routes cache cleared';
});

// Clear config cache:
Route::get('/config-cache', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'Config cache cleared';
});

// Clear application cache:
Route::get('/clear-cache', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return 'Application cache cleared';
});

// Clear view cache:
Route::get('/view-clear', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    return 'View cache cleared';
});
```

Comment: I don't think you get to run terminal commands in shared hosting. Also when you say css not working, are you getting 404 for these files in the browser?

Comment: do you have access to terminal in your shared hosting ?

Comment: How you transfer your app to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ProjectFolder/bootstrap/cache then rename config.php to anything you want eg. config.php_old and reload your site